# Exo player does not trigger onPlaybackState to buffering when live player has poor connection and onLoadError is triggering

Tags: android, exoplayer

Exo player does not trigger onPlaybackState to buffering when live player has poor connection and onLoadError is triggering.

My player freeze when cannot get new chunks, onLoadError triggers, but playbackState does not trigger and change to buffering. Why? also isPlaying return true despite player is frozen and it is not playing

I expect that player will trigger STATE_BUFFERING to be able to handle the view.